# Streaming Static/Live media online smoothly in ASP.NET/C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, real-time, live-streaming

I am currently working on a project that requires live video streaming, in 
    **realtime** which could be from a file or a webcam cast just like a video chat or ustream.tv. I am not getting exactly how that works and how it changes the bitrate dynamically depending upon the bandwidth of the viewer and the device type.
For example: if i am using a 2mbps connection then the video is streamed to me at a high bitrate and otherwise for mobile devices with a lower bandwidth support.
And I have gone thru examples and searched for softwares like Microsoft's SmoothSTreaming, but I want that to be totally custom made.

If you have used the streaming option in VLC media player, that supports online streaming of videos and also live streaming.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [Microsoft Media Platform: Player Framework](http://smf.codeplex.com/).